# Bochs "vgaromimage" Error?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootloader, bochs

[image]While Testing my Boot-loader in Bochs I have used following configuration file

```
# ROM and VGA BIOS images ---------------------------------------------

romimage:    file=BIOS-bochs-latest, address=0xf0000 
vgaromimage: VGABIOS-lgpl-latest 

# boot from floppy using our disk image -------------------------------

floppya: 1_44=a:, status=inserted  # Boot from drive A

# logging and reporting -----------------------------------------------

log:         OSDev.log             # All errors and info logs will output to OSDev.log
error:       action=report 
info:        action=report
```

But while executing it i am getting the error "vgaromimage directive malformed".
Any help?? I have saved my configuration file Conf.bxrc?

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: The line should look like: `vgaromimage: file=path/to/file/VGABIOS-lgpl-latest`. You forgot at least the `file=` part.

Comment: Sir it works but now it gives error:ROM: couldn't open ROM image file BIOS-Bochs-latest.

Comment: Search for the file `BIOS-Bochs-latest`, add its path and read the original documentation: http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/

Comment: I find solution to my problem error is generated not due to path but due to address mentioned in configuration file i have replaced the address 0xf0000 by 0xe0000 and it works,because The size of the Bochs BIOS is 128kb, not 64kb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find solution to my problem error is generated not due to path but due to address mentioned in configuration file i have replaced the address 0xf0000 by 0xe0000 and it works,because The size of the Bochs BIOS is 128kb, not 64kb –